# Google Play Services Base Being Resolved to Version not in Dependencies

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-services

While updating the google-play-services libraries used in my React Native Android project, upon building I'm getting this error:

> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base is being
>   requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but
>   resolves to 10.2.4. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies
>   tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

But when I run `./gradlew :app:dependencies` there is no mention of version 10.2.4 of any library.

Here is the dependencies section of my build.grade:

```
implementation project(':react-native-cookies')
implementation(project(':react-native-google-places')) {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms';
}
implementation(project(':react-native-maps')) {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms';
}
implementation(project(':react-native-fbsdk')) {
    exclude(group: 'com.facebook.android', module: 'facebook-android-sdk');
    exclude group: 'com.android.support';
}
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
implementation(project(':tipsi-stripe')) {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support';
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms';
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase';
}
implementation(project(':react-native-camera')) {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support';
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms';
}
implementation(project(":react-native-google-signin")){         
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms";
}
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
```

How can I resolve this issue? Thank you

**EDIT:** I noticed that my react-native-google-places dependency was behind a version, and after updating it the error message has changed to:

> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base is being requested
>   by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to
>   **11.6.2**.

Looking at the build.gradle for react-native-google-places reveals that it is indeed including `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.2`, but I would have expected the dependency to be excluded due to the `exclude group:` in my app's build.gradle (see above).

Comment: Can you try using dependencyInsight (as per https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/inspecting_dependencies.html#sec:identifying_reason_dependency_selection) to see which of your other dependencies might be trying to pull in play-services-base at 11.6.2 ?

Comment: I managed to get my project to build again, I think it was due to using a more recent version of the google-services plugin > 4 (in buildscript { dependencies { ... } } ). Using version 3.2.1 seemed to fix it for me, not sure if I might have changed something else in the process though.. Thanks for the help!